# Windows Defender reports my application as malware

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-defender

It's a simple Windows Forms application using the Google Cloud SDK. I have properly signed the application using a purchased SHA256 Comodo CSC.

My solution has a single EXE file along with dependencies (DLL files and images) that is embedded inside an MSI (using the *Setup Project*).

I have signed both the EXE and MSI file using `signtool` appropriately and have verified the signatures. Virustotal.com report shows all green. I've submitted a false positive to Windows Defender [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission) multiple times including individual files, and it came back as `Clean`.

I am perplex at this point. Is there anything else I should try? Windows Defender (latest updates) still reports it has a trojan.

[image: Windows Defender false positives]

Comment: Have you scanned your exe with another Virus checker just to make sure? If it is a false positive the only thing you can do is what you have done, and or make and exclusion for it

Comment: I have scanned using a bunch of online scanners and they all came out green. Is there any common ones you'd recommend? I can make exclusions but asking customers to do so will be ugly.

Comment: If its simple, im curious to know what happens if you comment everything out, and whats actually causing it

Comment: I did that and it’s the same issue. Only thing I left was references to google cloud sdk dlls in project.

Comment: If you add that reference to a newly created project is still still flagged as a virus?

Comment: I created a separate blank winforms app with single form and a button. Even this form exe is getting caught by Defender as Malware.

Comment: @xoail did you ever resolve this issue? If so, can you share the outcome?